# Can LocalStack manage resource ARN?

Tags: localstack

I use LocalStack to virtualize APIGateway resources (usage plans, API-Keys). I would like to use the **tag-resource** command from ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI class to add or update tags on resources but one of the parameters required is the resource ARN, when running the **get-resource** command I get an emty ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI array. Is there a way to have LocalStack manage resource ARN?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Localstack doesn't support resource tagging through the ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI API. However, there is always the option to use the service API; in the case you describe above, one option is to use "get-api-keys" and "get-usage-plan-keys"